# How to get x and y from canvas in center of window

Tags: html, canvas

I have been unsuccessful at trying to get the mouse coords on a canvas that sits in a div with auto margin.  I have a fiddle set up and Im hoping that someone can see what the problem is.

The logic behind the canvas is correct if I remove the margin but with the margin it's off by the dimensions of the offset.

http://jsfiddle.net/mcgraw73/Mfafz/

```
function init() {
    FGcanvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseDown, false);
    FGcanvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseUp, false);
    FGcanvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseMove, false);
}

function mouseDown(e) {
  rect.startX = e.clientX - FGcanvas.offsetLeft
  rect.startY = e.clientY - FGcanvas.offsetTop;
  drag = true;
}

function mouseUp() {
  drag = false;
}

function mouseMove(e) {
  if (drag) {
    rect.w = (e.clientX - rect.startX) - FGcanvas.offsetLeft; //(event.clientX - rect.start.x) - canvas.offsetLeft
    rect.h = (e.clientY - rect.startY) - FGcanvas.offsetTop;
    FGcontext.clearRect(0,0,FGcanvas.width,FGcanvas.height);
    draw();
  }
}


function draw() {
  FGcontext.clearRect(0,0,FGcanvas.width,FGcanvas.height);
  FGcontext.fillRect(rect.startX, rect.startY, rect.w, rect.h);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly certain because I rely so much on jQuery, but I don't think you can get the offset values of an element when it's in absolute.

So why not get the position from the parent div that is not in absolute ? I replaced this :

```
FGcanvas.offsetLeft
FGcanvas.offsetTop
```

With :

```
document.getElementById('ramRod').offsetLeft
document.getElementById('ramRod').offsetTop
```

I also removed the position:relative that you specified here :

```
body, header, aside, footer, div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

It only affected the body since you specify it again for all other elements.

Hope this was helpful ! (First answer on this site !)

Edit: Oh yeah forgot the link, here's my updated fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZDXWP/